# Add WebApi 2 to existing project - Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ninject

I have existing project ASP.NET MVC 4. I want to add to the project WebApi2. So I install WebApi2 in Nuget and create ApiController. When I running project then I got a error

> The IControllerFactory 'MvcApplication.Infrastructure.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'api'.

My NinjectControllerFactory:

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private IKernel ninjectKernel;

    public NinjectControllerFactory()
    {
        ninjectKernel = KernelSingleton.Instance.GetStandardKernel();
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return controllerType == null
            ? null
            : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // TODO: Add any additional configuration code.

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Main RouteConfig is empty because I have two areas.

```
internal static class RouteConfig
{
    internal static void RegisterRoutes(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}

internal static class RouteConfig
{
    internal static void RegisterRoutes(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "User_default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your WebApi routes and MVC routes. It sounds like the problem is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have moved your "default" route to be an area, you will need to reverse the order of registration in your `Global.asax`.

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

Should be:

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

Otherwise, any route that begins with `/api` will hit your default route and look for a controller named `api`.